# Calculating distance 'r' and gradient orientation (phi) for each edge pixel for implementing Generalized Hough Transform in opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to implement the generalized hough transform. I want to calculate distance 'r' and gradient orientation (phi) for each edge pixel.
I don't know how to do that and I need a simple code.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to look at OpenCV's implementation of GHT.

You can find it in file generalized_hough.cpp that located in opencv\modules\imgproc\src\ folder.